# google cloud Import data from Cloud Storage Could not complete the operation

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

it my first time using google cloud. 
I am setting up everything and I was going to add a sample database to my google cloud account to test few things, however when I try to import my sampleDB I get this error:

> Could not complete the operation.

I have already make a bucket and imported my sql file in there,

this is my sample sql file:

```
> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS student DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
> COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci; USE student;
> 
> CREATE TABLE person (   id int(11) NOT NULL,   name varchar(25) NOT
> NULL,   age int(3) NOT NULL,   sex text,   email text NOT NULL,  
> study varchar(20) NOT NULL,   birthday date NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB
> DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
> 
> INSERT INTO person (id, `name`, age, sex, email, study, birthday)
> VALUES (1, 'Saeed', 30, 'M', 'nakafisarrd@gmail.com', 'computer',
> '1987-04-30');
> 
> ALTER TABLE person   ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

this is [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbazHnZR8AA) I am following.
further more I have installed google app engine sdk for node. is doesn show me any error so I cant figure out what is going wrong here!

Comment: Are you really working with App Engine? Where are you trying to import your data, to Cloud SQL, or Datastore?

Comment: @Yandrak3 I download the google cloud SDK shell, I have a nodejs app alredy built I want to put it on cloud, But I cant, have any idea??

Comment: If you want to deploy a NodeJS application to Google Cloud Platform you should use [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart) (the Standard version is easier to use), but that has nothing to do with the tutorial you shared in the previous comment.

Comment: @Yandrak3 yes, I have to deploy a nodejs app in cloud, then I have to see how I can use postgres in google cloud and I was going to test it. Thus the tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing two topics here, so I will guide you through both process:

· **First**, you want to create a Cloud SQL instance importing a `*.sql` file, as explained in the tutorial you followed. However, bear in mind that this tutorial is using MySQL, so you should be creating a PostgreSQL instance instead if that fits your environment better. I would also recommend you to follow the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#mysqldump) on that topic, as it is explained in a clear way how to achieve what you want to do. I have tested the script you provided in a 2nd Generation MySQL instance changing the first line from `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS student DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;` to `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS student;` and it worked.

· **Second**, you want to upload your NodeJS application to the Google Cloud Platform, and with that purpose I suggest using App Engine. As of today, NodeJS support is only available in App Engine Flexible, so you can also follow a [guided quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart) in the documentation.

So I would recommend you to first clarify if you want to use either MySQL or PostgreSQL, create a Cloud SQL instance that matches your requirements, and then import the `.sql` file you shared. Everything should work fine.